# Convert NSURL to NSData from didPickMediaItems

Tags: ios, swift, mpmediapickercontroller

I can't seem to convert NSURL to NSData. The NSURL appears when printed out, but then when I try to convert it to NSData, the audioData variable keeps returning nil.

```
func mediaPicker(mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController!, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection!)
{
    selectedSong = mediaItemCollection.items[0] as MPMediaItem

    songUrl = selectedSong.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as? NSURL
    println("\(songUrl)")

    audioData = NSData(contentsOfURL: songUrl) as NSData
    println("\(audioData)")
}
```

**Edited Code to Catch the Error**

*songUrl is the URL address of a song located on my iPod library*

```
    var errorPointer:NSErrorPointer!
    audioData = NSData(contentsOfURL: songUrl, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedAlways, error: errorPointer)
    if audioData == nil
    {
        println("\(errorPointer)")
    }
```

This code prints the error: **"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"** onto my console

**Edit #2**

Using the format in the error format in the answer below, I now get the error:

An Error Occurred: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)" UserInfo=0x146f4a90 {NSURL=ipod-library://item/item.m4a?id=3210273692689505570}

Comment: use [`NSData(contentsOfURL: options: error:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/initWithContentsOfURL:options:error:) and let us know what the error returned is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I wrote your code like so:

    audioData = NSData(contentsOfURL: songUrl, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedAlways, error: NSErrorPointer())

although i'm not sure I initialized the errorpointer correctly, there wasn't any error printout on my console.

Comment: There shouldn't be any output on the console. You need to log error.

Comment: @rdelmar cool, thanks for the tip, I'll try that out and get back to you

Comment: Yes, do not declare "`NSErrorPointer()`" *within* the `contentsOfURL` call.  Declare it outside, pass it in via `contentsOfURL` *as a parameter* and then print out the error if `audioData` comes back nil.

Comment: What is `songUrl`, add that to your question.

Comment: Go and read-up on error parameters. You really do need to know about them, they are quite helpful, even quicker than a SO question.

Comment: See the code in the answer below, an answer only for the formatting.

Comment: @Zaph I've been trying for a while now to figure out what Cocoa Error 256 is, but I haven't had any luck yet. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The URL is only appropriate with AVFoundation; NSData won't be able to do a thing with the NSURL. From Apple docs: "Usage of the URL outside of the AV Foundation framework is not supported."

Answer (score 0):

The URL is only appropriate with `AVFoundation`, `NSData` won't be able to do a thing with the `NSURL`.
From Apple docs:

> "Usage of the URL outside of the AV Foundation framework is not supported."

Example of how to code the error parameter:

```
var error: NSError?
audioData = NSData(contentsOfURL: songUrl, options: .DataReadingUncached, error: &error)

if audioData == nil {
    if let unwrappedError = error {
        println("An Error Occurred: \(unwrappedError)")
    }
}
```

Comment: ugh, i'm sorry, i'll try again. The whole NSErrorPointer threw me off a bit, I thought it was asking for something else as opposed to a regular NSError. Thanks for working with me.

Comment: Ok, now I think I have the correct error...The program prints unwrappedError as "An Error Occurred: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)" UserInfo=0x146f4a90 {NSURL=ipod-library://item/item.m4a?id=3210273692689505570}"